How to determine what exact authentication type was used?
I need to identify which of the following was exactly used to authenticate user:

Passcode
Password
Pattern
Biometric fingerprint
Biometric facial recognition
Biometric iris recognition
Biometric voice recognition
Behavioral biometric

Right now, I am just able to differentiate between the DEVICE_CREDENTIAL and BIOMETRIC_STRONG based on below
int BIOMETRIC_STRONG
Any biometric (e.g. fingerprint, iris, or face) on the device that meets or exceeds the requirements for Class 3 (formerly Strong), as defined by the Android CDD.

int BIOMETRIC_WEAK
Any biometric (e.g. fingerprint, iris, or face) on the device that meets or exceeds the requirements for Class 2 (formerly Weak), as defined by the Android CDD.

int DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
The non-biometric credential used to secure the device (i.e., PIN, pattern, or password).

UseCase:: I am building an application in which after authentication I need to send what verification method was used to verify the user to the backend. Using android BiometricManager getAutheticationType I just get below info but I need further classification asper above shared list.
String authType = switch (result.getAuthenticationType()) {
                    case BiometricPrompt.AUTHENTICATION_RESULT_TYPE_BIOMETRIC -> "13";
                    case BiometricPrompt.AUTHENTICATION_RESULT_TYPE_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL -> "10";
                    case BiometricPrompt.AUTHENTICATION_RESULT_TYPE_UNKNOWN -> "10";
                    default -> "10";
                };


Used for what? What is the use case? Provide more context to the question.

updated usecase

Sorry, but what you want is not supported by Android.
